# JXLS - add formula for blank cells, formula just disappears

Tags: java, excel, spring, jxls

I created a report with JXLS and an excel template. I have a bunch of cells/columns pulling data from my database, then I have a few columns that are blank, and then I have some formulas/conditionals in a few columns in my report as well. The issue I am having is that one of the formulas, needs to run/ multiply two blank columns (someone will download the report and input the numbers manually in those blank columns), and when I run the generate the report through my Java app, the column with the formula comes up as =0. Anyways to get the formula to stick, so the people manually entering the numbers in the blank columns do not have to add/input the formula themselves?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get Jxls to process `AC` and `AD` cells by putting a dummy JEXL expression in there.

The simplest way is to put `${null}` into `AC` and `AD` cells in your template.

Comment: Thanks! This should work well enough, even though they will have to push F2 and enter to evaluate the column once they fill in AC and AD.